# Responsive email breaks on smartphone email client apps

Tags: html, email

I'm editing a bought responsive email template. Below you can see the structure used.

[image: Desktop and mobile versions]

The email is responsive on the **web version** and on **desktop browser** email clients. But when testing it on mobile email apps like Gmail, the structure breaks, and on Yahoo it displays the desktop version.

After cleaning up the code, and testing diferent versions... I think the problem is in the section where there is a background full width and then a normal width table with 2 images.

I tried putting the background on the top `<table>` and then on the `<td>` but it still don't work on mobile email apps like Gmail or Yahoo.

I don't know if I'm missing up something, or I'm doing something wrong. It only breaks on mobile email apps.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code of the top section.

```html
<table class="main-header" data-module="Header" data-bgcolor="Header" data-bg="Header" style="position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vUQUDS-TL6Q/hqdefault.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 40%;" background="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vUQUDS-TL6Q/hqdefault.jpg" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tbody><tr>
         <td class="zay600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" border="0" width="90%" class="zay600">
             <!-- img -->
             <tbody><tr>
               <td align="center">
                 <table align="center" class="zay600" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                   <!-- logo -->
                   <tbody><tr>
                     <td>
                       <table align="left" class="zay3-3" width="120" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                         <tbody><tr>
                           <td height="40">
                           </td>
                         </tr>
                         <!-- logo -->
                         <tr>
                           <td align="center" valign="middle" style="line-height:0px;">
                            <img style="display:block; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; border:0px;" src="http://www.dickson-constant.com/medias/images/catalogue/api/m654-grey-680.jpg" width="249" height="70" alt="img">
                          </td>
                         </tr>
                         <!-- end logo -->
                       </tbody></table>
                       <!--Space-->
                       <table width="1" height="30" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                         <tbody><tr>
                           <td height="30" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
                             <p style="padding-left: 24px;">
                               &nbsp;                                                                                    </p>
                           </td>
                         </tr>
                       </tbody></table>
                       <table align="right" class="zay3-3" width="280" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                         <tbody><tr>
                           <td height="50">
                           </td>
                         </tr>
                         <!-- logo -->
                         <tr>
                           <td align="center">
                             <table class="zay-inner" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                               <tbody><tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="line-height:0px;"><img style="display:block; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; border:0px;" src="http://www.dickson-constant.com/medias/images/catalogue/api/m654-grey-680.jpg" width="280" height="36" alt="img">
                              </td></tr>
                             </tbody></table>
                           </td>
                         </tr>
                         <!-- end logo -->
                       </tbody></table>
                       <!--End Space-->
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <!-- menu -->
                   <!-- end menu -->
                 </tbody></table>
               </td>
             </tr>
             <!-- end logo -->
             <tr>
               <td height="100" class="header-td">
               </td>
             </tr>
             <!-- subtitle -->
             <tr>
               <td>
                 <!-- content -->
                 <table class="zay600" width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                   <tbody><tr>
                     <td align="center">
                       <table border="0" width="184" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container580">
                         <tbody><tr>
                           <td align="center" valign="middle" style="line-height:0px;">
                             
                           </td>
                         </tr>
                       </tbody></table>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   
                   <tr>
                     <td align="center">
                       <!-- img -->
                       <table align="center" class="zay3-3" width="275" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                         <tbody><tr>
                           <td align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                             
                           </td>
                         </tr>
                       </tbody></table>
                       <!-- end img -->
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   
                   <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <!-- img -->
                      <table align="center" class="zay3-3" width="275" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                          <td align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                            
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody></table>
                      <!-- end img -->
                    </td>
                  </tr>                 
                  
                  
                 </tbody></table>
                 <!-- end content -->
               </td>
             </tr>
             <!-- end subtitle -->
             <tr>
               <td height="100" class="header-td">
               </td>
             </tr>            
             
           </tbody></table>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody></table>
```

Comment: It's a nightmare to have a good result everywhere with an email. You can use a tool like emailonacid to try to debug your template.

Comment: @Guillaume Totally... Even between Gmail in android 4.4 and newer versions of android, the email is displayed diferently.